# An old-school HTML bug involving unclosed tags

Tags: html

Have a look at [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20150221125906/http://www.sewingandembroiderywarehouse.com/embtrb.htm) web-page. Scroll down a little.

Alright, we all know what's wrong with it, but what's causing the bug? I came up with this minimal example:

```html
<h3>Title <foobar> Some text.
<h3>Title <foobar> Some text.
<h3>Title <foobar> Some text.
```

Tested on Chromium and Firefox. You can replace `<foobar>` with any tag, including a tag that doesn't exist. Closing the nonsensical tags fixes the bug, though:

```html
<h3>Title <foobar> Some text.</foobar>
<h3>Title <foobar> Some text.</foobar>
<h3>Title <foobar> Some text.</foobar>
```

This is seemingly to do with the precise way in which modern browsers auto-close open tags. Can anyone shed some light on the situation?

Comment: I think it happens due to `h3` default value of attribute `font-size: 1.17em`, where `1em` is font-size of parent and if it's not defined different in child, then its value inherited. When browser meets any closing child tag, it try to close unclosed parent, because it can't do it within plain text. Along with this an interesting issue how browsers define node type for undefined tags.

Comment: @Banzay I'm not sure. In `<h3>Foo<h3>Bar</h3></h3>`, "Foo" and "Bar" appear the same size.

Comment: Obviously browser recognizes undefined tag as inline level element and looks for its explicit close or close of its parent.  `<h3>Title <foobar> Some text.
<h3>Title <foobar> Some text.</h3>
<h3>Title <foobar> Some text.`

Answer (score -2):

I think the bug is caused because the h3 tries to size things up but then if you put another h3 tag inside a thing that makes things big it makes it even bigger. The extra foobar tag that is closed might also accidentially make the h3 tag closed.
Also, Thanks for reading this